# If a Borel measure is positive on every nonempty set, can it be finite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $\mathscr{B}_R$, which is strictly positive on any non empty set. Can it be finite?

I thought about finding a very fine partition of $R$, and claim that the measure is infinity if you sum up all the measure on each subset. But I think in order to do that, we need uncountably many positive terms to sum, but additivity of measure only holds for countable sum.

I'm very stuck. Could you give me some suggestions or comments?

Thank you.

Comment: Your title says "every nonempty set", but your question says "on a nonempty set". Could you clarify?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x$ you have $a_x=\mu(\{x\})>0$. Since there are uncountably many $x$ this implies that $\mu$ is infinite.

Except you're worried that we only have countable additivity. Fine: Say $E_n$ is the set of $x$ with $a_x>1/n$. There exists $n$ so that $E_n$ is uncountable. In particular $E_n$ contains an infinite countable subset $F$. And so countable additivity shows that $$\mu(F)\ge\sum_{j=1}^\infty 1/n=\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask a further question? Why is it that there is n such that En is uncountable? I tried to derive contradiction assuming the converse, but with no success. Could you explain?

Comment: This is really something you should know. Note that the union of the $E_n$ is all of $\Bbb R$. A countable union of countable sets is...

Comment: There's the contradiction. I see. Thank you.